# Redundant relationship?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, table-relationships

I'm trying to design a database model and I have a question.

I need to represent this:

An order could have zero or one QAP.
An order could have one or more E-Report.
An E-Report must have one QAP.

To represent this, I have this model:

[image]

If an orden doesn't have a QAP, user must select one to add it to an E-Report. If an order has a QAP, user doesn't need to select one to add it to an E-Report because all E-Reports will have the order's QAP.

A user will receive an Orden ,adn then he will fill up E-Reports. I'm not interested in orders, I am interested in E-Reports filled by user, and QAP have information needed to fill it up.

My problem is **if Order hasn't got a QAP E-Reports could have different QAP**.
For example, Order1 doesn't have a QAP, but it has two E-Report:

- E-Report1 has QAP1, and
- E-Report2 has QAP2.

**Is this database design correct?

 I'm not sure if repeat qapId column in Order table and in E-Report table is correct.**

Comment: Yes, but where is the problem that needs solving or help?

Comment: I'm asking if this design is correct. I'm not sure if adding qapId column to Order and E-Report table is correct.

Comment: Based on how you described it, it looks good to me.  You'll just need some business logic somewhere to ensure data integrity; e.g. if an Ereport is assigned to an order that already has a qapId, what happens to the qapIds in the Ereports and Orders table?

Comment: @VansFannel - Is it possible for an `EReport` to have a null `orderId`? Or do all `EReports` have to have an `Order` at all times?

Comment: @JoelBrown: No, an `EReport` always will have an `orderId`. Yes, `EReports` will have an `Order` always.

Comment: @VansFannel - Since EReports can have _different_ QAPs before the mandatory Order gets a QAP, there is no way to use declarative referential integrity (alone) to represent your constraints.  The model you have now is what you need to use, in combination with some procedural logic to impose your rule that EReports must share the same QAP if their Order has one.

Comment: @JoelBrown: the right answer it's your last comment. If you add an answer with it, I'll check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since EReports can have different QAPs before the mandatory Order gets a QAP, there is no way to use declarative referential integrity (alone) to represent your constraints. The model you have now is what you need to use, in combination with some procedural logic to impose your rule that EReports must share the same QAP if their Order has one.

Answer (score 1):

> An order could have zero or one QAP.

Making Order.qapid a nullable foreign key will fit this requirement.

> An order could have one or more E-Report.

Making EReport.orderid a non-nullable foreign key will *accommodate* that requirement, but won't quite fit it. There's no declarative way to require that every order have at least one EReport.  You *could* do that using updatable views, triggers, etc, though. But it's not crystal clear that you mean "Every order must have at least one EReport,"  which implies that a row in EReport is created at the same time as a row in Order.

> An E-Report must have one QAP.

Making EReport.qaoid a non-nullable foreign key will fit this requirement.

> If an order has a QAP, user doesn't need to select one to add it to an
>   E-Report because all E-Reports will have the order's QAP.

If you're copying an order's QAP to an EReport, you might be approaching this whole problem the wrong way. You also said

> My problem is if Order hasn't got a QAP E-Reports could have different
>   QAP.

which implies that there's only one QAP per order.  It might be that you need to store one and only one QAP in the Order table, and *no qapid at all* in the EReport table.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't think that if an Order hasn't got a QAP E-Reports could have different QAP will imply that there's only one QAP per order. If Order doesn't have a qapId, its E-Reports could have differents qapId.

Comment: @VansFannel: You said that, if Order hasn't got a QAP, then E-reports that have different QAPs is a problem. (See the last quote from you in my answer.) If E-reports aren't supposed to have different QAPs, then they must need to have the *same* QAP--so only one QAP per order.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to represent a situation where `Order` doesn't have `QAP`, but it's `EReport`s do, and it must be the same one?

Well, since `EReport` must always have `Order`, you can omit the `EReport.qapId` and rely on `Order.qapId`, something like this:

[image]

If `Order.forOrder` is false, then your client application can interpret `Order.qapId` as if it only applies to child `EReport`s, otherwise it applies to both `Order` and `EReport`s.

Comment: If Order doesn't have a qapId, its E-Reports could have differents qapId.

Comment: @VansFannel There is no `EReport.qapId`, so there is nothing to differ.